# form-login.php version 4.1.0 is out of date error after WordPress update with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce with wordpress. I updated wordpress version to 6.0.3 and now i am getting this warning in admin page for the template.

> woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php version 4.1.0 is out of date. The
> core version is 6.0.0,
> **Woocommerce is Version 7.0.0 and PHP is version 8.0**

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Download woocommerce plugin and move myaccount/form-login.php file to theme folder

Comment: woocommerce plugin is installed and site is running with it.

Comment: Move myaccount/form-login.php file to theme folder or update the woocommerce plugin